# How to remap by Karabiner Enter->Shift only when Ctrl is pressed?

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I am stuck with a problem with a non-trivial complex modification for Karabiner-Elements and I hope there are experts in this stuff here. :)
I have posted this question as an [issue](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2673) on GitHub, but without much success. :(

So, here is what I want to achieve:

- `return_or_enter` normally works as it should;
- if `left_control` is held down, `return_or_enter` works as `shift`.

Thus it is should be possible to use ctrl+tab and ctrl+enter+tab to switch tabs in Safari.
You would think I am crazy, but I just use Advantage2 with modified layout, so I have all these three keys under my left hand. :)

Here is what I wrote in the `profiles.complex_modifications.rules` section of my `karabiner.json`:

```json
{
    "description": "Enter as supportive Shift",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "description": "Left Ctrl Up/Down",
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "left_control",
                "modifiers": { "optional": ["any"] }
            },
            "to": [{
                "key_code": "right_control"
            }],
            "to_if_held_down": [{ "set_variable": {
                "name": "enter-as-shift mode is on",
                "value": 1
            } }],
            "to_after_key_up": [{ "set_variable": {
                "name": "enter-as-shift mode is on",
                "value": 0
            } }]
        },
        {
            "description": "Enter Keystroke",
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "return_or_enter",
                "modifiers": { "optional": ["any"] }
            },
            "conditions": [{
                "type": "variable_if",
                "name": "enter-as-shift mode is on",
                "value": 1
            }],
            "to": [{
                "key_code": "left_shift"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Alack, it does not work. Each manipulator works correctly — the variable is set and unset, the remap without condition do its job — but together, linked by the variable, they are seems to be totally broken. :(

Can someone point me what am I missing? Is it even possible with Karabiner?
Thank you.

P.S. If it does matter, I use Karabiner-Elements 13.3.0 & macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: I just looked into your code and noticed that "Karabiner EventViewer" recognises your variable as "1" as long as you press left_control but in tab "Main" left_control is shown as "right_control" (as intended) but immediately afterwards registered as "key_up".                                                                  So when you "add" return_or_enter to your combination, right_control is no longer active. You might try to push the left-to-right-control into your "Enter Keystroke" part.

Comment: I looked once more into your script –
… and it worked like it's supposed to (= in TextEdit it typed some capital letters)

Hm, maybe some of your "from:" elements are used in a previous "manipulators" ?!? You might try to push it to the beginning of your karabiner.json file.